# Jmeter - UPDATED - Duration Assertion on While Controller (JDBC Sampler)? - UPDATED

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jmeter, assertion

My current environment: JMeter v2.11, remote Oracle 12, JDK 7

There is a system (A) that will send 2000 SOAP/XML submissions (per hour) into a receiving system (B). System B will insert a new row to the database table (for each new submission) setting the application.status column value to numeric value of 1.  System (B) processes the requests and updates the application.status column from numeric value of 1 to numeric value of 6 once the processing is complete and the submissions are 'approved'.

I have a requirement that states these A to B submissions need to be 'approved' within 60 seconds - I am trying to setup my thread to verify this.

My current workings (after some start up help from Dmitri T) are as follows:

`Thread Group
-Beanshell Sampler (to create an XML message)
-Beanshell Sampler (to submit XML to a web service)
-While Controller-->${__javaScript("${status_1}" != "6")} 
--Duration Assertion-->60000 milliseconds (Duration)
--JDBC Request-->select status from application where applicationID = (select max(application_id) from application); VarName = status`

Currently, my Thread Group will run and I will get multiple JDBC Requests executed until either the JDBC Request takes longer than the Duration Assertion value OR until the status value in the application table is updated to 6 (which equates to 'Approved' status).

This is NOT what I need.

**I don't want to verify whether the JDBC request takes longer than the Duration value, it will never take longer than the Duration value, what I need the Duration Assertion for is to fail if the change from application.status=1 to application.status=6 takes longer than 60 seconds**

As I state above - it won't prove my requirement to verify if the JDBC request takes longer than the Duration Assertion value (it never will), I need the Duration Assertion to check the application.status change takes less than 60 seconds.

I've tried the following:

`Thread Group
-While Controller-->${__javaScript("${status_1}" != "6")} 
--Duration Assertion-->60000 milliseconds (Duration)
--JDBC Request-->select status from application where applicationID = (select max(application_id) from application); VarName = status`

`Thread Group
-While Controller-->${__javaScript("${status_1}" != "6")} 
--JDBC Request-->select status from application where applicationID = (select max(application_id) from application); VarName = status
--Duration Assertion-->60000 milliseconds (Duration)`

`Thread Group
-While Controller-->${__javaScript("${status_1}" != "6")} 
--JDBC Request-->select status from application where applicationID = (select max(application_id) from application); VarName = status
---Duration Assertion-->60000 milliseconds (Duration)`

I'm running out of ideas! - As with my previous requests, I appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Cheers!

Comment: Upvoted for visibility.  I could use a feature like this in JMeter

Answer (score 0):

Just move your Duration Assertion one level up (the same level as JDBC Request, not as a child of JDBC Request) - in that case it will be applied to While Controller duration, not the single request.

To learn more regarding assertions scope, cost and interoperability see [How to Use JMeter Assertions in 3 Easy Steps](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide.

Comment: I tried that but it wasn't working - or it was but it isn't what I need.  @Dmitri T.  The Duration Assertion is checking whether the JDBC request is taking longer than the Duration value - this isn't what I need to verify - I need to verify the status change in db doesn't take longer than 60 secs.  I have updated the query text to hopefully provide more clarity in regards to my confusion.  Again - cheers for the help Dmitri T.

Comment: Perhaps you could try putting your While Controller under a [Simple Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller) and apply duration assesrtion to it.

Comment: Hi - @Dmitri T.  Unfortunately - the Simple Controller parent option didn't work either.  I think I'm going to have to abandon that as nothing I do appears to get the Duration Assertion to associate with the While Controller rather than the JDBC request.  Many thanks for the help though.